# Cydia SBSettings "Free Up Memory"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, cydia

Does anyone know how to add the SBSettings "Free Up Memory" to their application? I'm developing an app in iOS5 and ARC doesn't appear to be releasing memory as often as I would like.

How can one write that functionality in their app using Objective-C?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just allocate memory until you get a memory warning then free all allocated data.

Comment: ARC is not garbage collection, so it can't "release memory as ofter as you'd like".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARC releases objects when they are supposed to be released. It is not a solution to free up all memory because you are allocating too much. My suggestion is that you change your app to be more efficient.